# Deleting EFI partition

Tags: windows, diskpart, system-reserved-partition

I'm trying to delete a Windows EFI system partition on my HDD. I decided that I want to move the boot files from the HDD onto one of my SSDs as the HDD is old and I'm afraid of it eventually dying on me, so I successfully made a copy of the EFI partition and everything works great. Now when I go to delete the old EFI partition on my HDD, diskpart spits out an error no matter which methods I try. I was wondering if there is a way of deleting an old EFI partition without resorting to 3rd party applications that I often see recommended when I google my problem.

I'm using Windows 10.

Here's my diskpart output when trying to delete the duplicate partition:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          238 GB  2048 KB
  Disk 1    Online         2794 GB  1024 KB   *    *
  Disk 2    Online          465 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 3    Online          465 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Dynamic Data      1794 GB    17 KB
  Partition 2    System             513 MB  1794 GB
  Partition 3    Dynamic Reserved  1024 KB  2794 GB
  Partition 4    Reserved           127 MB  2794 GB

DISKPART> select partition 2

Partition 2 is now the selected partition.

DISKPART> delete partition override

Virtual Disk Service error:
The operation is not supported by the object.


The specified command or parameters are not supported on this system.
```

Comment: You write "spitting", that's not a technical term. And you write "without resorting to 3rd party applications "  There's no great reason to insist on diskpart if diskpart seem to do it when you tried it, other than curiosity of how and if you can get diskpart to do it.  Trying something else isn't something you should call "resorting". Long time windows users have used various software to deal with partitions. Windows 98 didn't have diskpart.. We used to have fdisk but fdisk didn't do some things so other software was needed and very good.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to do it the MS Windows way in Windows, but not always and sometimes there's 3rd party software for Windows that is great for Windows. If you want to delete something, be open to various things. And some software is actually a pleasure to use.

Comment: @barlop You're right, "spitting" is not a technical term, but I doubt there was any confusion about what I meant when I said that diskpart "spits out an error." If you're so deeply offended by my verbiage, my sincerest apologies. Also trying something else is by definition "resorting," as using external software is undesirable (for me). I've visited many different sites each of which suggests its own sketchy proprietary software that I'd rather not install unless there is absolutely no way to do it through just Windows.

Comment: Windows is "proprietary" software.    It's not like every proprietary piece of software other than Windows is(to use your dodgy term) "sketchy".  Your habit of using non technical terms , and the way you do, just affects everything you write and your ability to communicate clearly and make sense is badly affected by it. There are many pieces of software that are tried and tested. Windows is just one(or some), of them.

Comment: @barlop If you think proprietary software written by Microsoft and software written by Random Inc. is the same I'm not sure what to say to you. I am open to suggestions however, preferably open-source.

Comment: @barlop Be careful with using terms like "dodgy." You might stop making sense!

Comment: I already considered that objection, but i'm using the word dodgy in a way that I can easily elaborate on , and that I can claarly define, and if i've already described why something is problematic(which I have), then, I can call it dodgy.. To just call something sketchy because it is third party or not from microsoft, is completely insane

Comment: @barlop It is insane. Unfortunately for you, what is more insane is the fact that you felt the need to point that out despite nobody ever saying that! Allow me to catch you up to the current century and elucidate what people may mean when they say "sketchy software." Generally, this is closed source software written by an unknown enterprise. This software can then be posted on a blogpost advertising itself to be solving the issue with no actual reviews confirming this claim to be true. (Note that the blogpost bit is not a necessary characteristic, any random site will do.)

Comment: @barlop Would you like to continue to obfuscate and be obtuse by pointlessly bringing up wording you deem to be problematic (which despite this has been entirely clear this whole time), or would you like to attempt to get at the heart of the issue of the original post? I'll gladly entertain you regardless of the option you choose.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use the `clean` command of the DISKPART utility.

**WARNING**
this will remove **ALL** partitions on the drive

There have been times when I have been unable to use Microsoft windows to perform low level disk operations and have resorted to booting of a USB stick with Linux on it.

Rough overview of the steps

1. Open Command Prompt and run as administrator
2. run DISKPART as you did before
3. select the disk
4. execute the clean command
5. exit DISKPART
6. use Disk Management tool to manipulate disk (right mouse click on the windows button [image]

using your example code

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          238 GB  2048 KB
  Disk 1    Online         2794 GB  1024 KB   *    *
  Disk 2    Online          465 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 3    Online          465 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: This is dangerous advice. `clean` will remove _all_ partitions. It is __highly unlikely__ OP wants this.

Comment: I agree with you that this is dangerous. I'll update the answer with a warning to match.